# Using ktor and exposed with postgresql for my back end, how should I send my resultrows to my users?

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am building an android app and the backend (remote server) im using ktor with exposed and hitting a postgresql data base.  I am just unsure upon getting my results back from queries how I should attempt to send those back to my user app on Android.  What would be the right way.  To have the user app install exposed library and just send the query results? format all the results to a json string and blast that?  Just don't know what would be ideal.

I haven't really attempted anything yet because I was looking for a "best practices" idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one "best practice" way to send the data from the server to the client. Normally it depends on your use case. However, one common way that I would suggest you use is to create RESTful-API.

This means:

- Requests and Responses to/from the server will be serialized to JSON.
- Confirm to HTTP verbs semantics (use GET to read data, PUT to update, etc).
- Use status code for error handling
- Follow the REST API guidelines for best practices (API versioning, end point names, pagination, etc)

To read more about REST API guidelines, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) is useful.

For Ktor, this will mean having a serializer, and then defining your routes. This [guide](https://ktor.io/docs/creating-http-apis.html#customer_routing) is useful for Ktor.

Although this is not the only way, but it will provide you with enough experience to explore others APIs (Custom API, RPC, SOAP, etc).

Comment: thanks so much.  By reading that ktor documentation that you linked I found out that I could make a list of serialized data classes and send that as a whole and ktor knows how to serialize and deserialize.  Hadn't realized it was that easy.  Now ill just make a dataclass for my result rows and send a list of them.  Easy peasy